# python cgi path confusion

Tags: python, cgi

newbee here! I am trying to understand CGI concept, and wrote a sample code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class cgiweb (SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
                print "Content-Type: text/html"
                print
                print 'Hello World'

server=SocketServer.TCPServer(("",8022),cgiweb)
server.serve_forever()
```

saved it as cgiwebserver.py script. Now I am trying to access the script in browser through address:

```
localhost:8022
```

its not connecting! and prints all the statement (in handler) in the terminal.

Am I typing the correct path? 
if no, then why? 
and what should be the correct path?

Comment: "Trying to understand CGI" is not a useful exercise in 2014. Learn WSGI, or even better a Python web framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` is not programming CGI.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class cgiweb(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello World')

server = SocketServer.TCPServer(("",8022),cgiweb)
server.serve_forever()
```

If you want to do CGI programming, you need to look [`CGIHTTPServer` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html). and should put CGI program (which print HTTP headers and body to standard output) in a separated file.

Comment: 'code'#!/usr/bin/python
import CGIHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class cgiw (CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
                print "Content-Type: text/html"
                print
                print 'Hello World'
server=SocketServer.TCPServer(("",8021),cgiw)
server.serve_forever()
'code'
even this is not working and same results!
@falsetru

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman, It's hard to read code in the comment, especially Python code.

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman, The code in the answer does not contain any `print` statement. Where are they come from? Did you try the code in the answer as is?